# Which transformation needed to make variance independent of population parameter?

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, asymptotics, central-limit-theorem

Suppose $s^2$ is the sample variance of a sample$(\text{of size }n)$ from a normal population with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2. \text{Here }s^2=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\overline{x})^2}{n-1} $
As we know $\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{(n-1)}$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/47013/565609) 
. Let $x\sim \chi^2_{(n-1)}$ then $E[x]=n-1$ and $Var[x]=2(n-1)$ 
\begin{align*} 
E\left[\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\sigma^2}\right]=E[x]&=n-1\\ 
\implies \frac{(n-1)}{\sigma^2}E[s^2] &=  n-1\\
\implies E[s^2]&=\sigma^2
\end{align*}
Similarly, 
\begin{align*} 
Var\left[\frac{(n-1)s^2}{\sigma^2}\right]=Var[x]&=2(n-1)\\ 
\implies \frac{(n-1)^2}{\sigma^4}E[s^2] &=2(n-1)\\
\implies  Var[s^2]&=\color{red}{\frac{2\sigma^4}{(n-1)} }
\end{align*} Now we need a function of $s^2$ whose variance will be independent of $\sigma^2.$ Let $f(s^2)$ be the required transformation.

> The required transformation is $$f(s^2)\stackrel{?}{=}\ln{s^2}$$

**Question:** How they get that transformation $?$ 

Similar things happen with Poisson variate and Binomial proportion with square root and $\sin^{-1}$ transformation. **So I need a general approach to get that transformation which will make variance independent of population parameter**.

Thanks for your time. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Search for [Variance-stabilizing_transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-stabilizing_transformation).

Comment: "The aim behind the choice of a variance-stabilizing transformation is to find a simple function f to apply to values x in a data set to create new values y=f(x) such that the variability of the values y is not related to their mean value." But I need the variability of the values y is not related to their variance(population) value? @StubbornAtom Sir

Comment: The wiki article might not be entirely clear. I gave you the keyword to look for the topic. (And I am no 'sir'.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and define the sample variance as $$S^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline X)^2$$

Here we are concerned with the large-sample behaviour of $S^2$, so it does not matter if we take $n$ as the divisor above instead of $n-1$.

By CLT it can be argued that $$\sqrt n(S^2-\sigma^2)\stackrel{L}\longrightarrow N(0,2\sigma^4)\tag{1}$$

And by '[Delta-method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method)', for a real-valued function $g$ such that $g'(\sigma^2)$ exists and $g'(\sigma^2)\ne 0$, it follows from $(1)$ that

$$\sqrt n(g(S^2)-g(\sigma^2))\stackrel{L}\longrightarrow N(0,2\sigma^4[g'(\sigma^2)]^2)\tag{2}$$

You have to solve for a $g$ such that *asymptotic* variance of $g(S^2)$ is free of $\sigma^2$.

So for some non-zero constant $c$, set $$\sqrt 2\sigma^2 g'(\sigma^2)=c$$

Therefore, $$\int g'(\sigma^2)\,d\sigma^2=\frac{c}{\sqrt 2}\int\frac{d\sigma^2}{\sigma^2}$$

Choosing $c=\sqrt 2$ and taking constant of integration to be zero, we have the required transformation $$g(\sigma^2)=\ln\sigma^2\quad,\text{ i.e. }\quad \color{blue}{g(S^2)=\ln S^2}$$

From $(2)$ you end up with $$\sqrt n(\ln(S^2)-\ln(\sigma^2))\stackrel{L}\longrightarrow N(0,2)$$

This is the application of *variance stabilizing transformation* on the sample variance from a normal population. The other transformations that you mention for the Poisson mean and Binomial proportion are derived similarly.

---

Result $(1)$ and many more can be found in [*A Course in Large Sample Theory*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0412043718) by Thomas Ferguson. The relevant part is on page 46 of the first edition (1996):

[image]

The main result used in this section is Cramer's Theorem on the asymptotic normality of functions of sample moments, studied through a Taylor-series expansion to one term.

[image]

Comment: what I know is **CLT** tells us $\color{red}{\sqrt{n}(\overline{x}-\mu)\text{ converge in distribution to a normal }N(0,\sigma^2)}$ And I know how to prove this but $\sqrt n(s^2-\sigma^2)\stackrel{L}\longrightarrow N(0,2\sigma^4)$ is looks new to me. So everything will be meaningful to me if you provide a source where I can get that proof $?$ I will accept your answer then. Thanks again  @StubbornAtom

Comment: @emonhossain Updated.

Comment: Really you help me a lot. Thanks @StubbornAtom